# How to draw MDC checkbox tickmark from template using svg file instead of using svg element directly in markdown

Tags: user-interface, svg, material-design, mdc-components

```
    <div class="mdc-form-field">
  <div class="mdc-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"
           id="my-checkbox"
           class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"/>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
           viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark__path"
              fill="none"
              stroke="white"
              d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="my-checkbox">My Checkbox Label</label>
</div>
```

I have tried something like

```
<div class="mdc-form-field">
    <div class="mdc-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="meetings" id="checkbox-meeting-{{meeting.id}}" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"
             value="{{meeting.id}}"/>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
          <img src="{% static 'images/checkbox-tick.svg' %}" class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label id="checkbox-meeting-{{meeting.id}}-label"
         for="checkbox-meeting-{{meeting.id}}" class="mdc-floating-label--float mdc-floating-label--float">
    {{ meeting.date|date:'m/d/Y' }}</label>
</div>
```

where my svg file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style>
        @import "@material/form-field/mdc-form-field";
        @import "@material/checkbox/mdc-checkbox";
    </style>
    <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"
          fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"></path>
</svg>
```

As a result only background colour inside checkbox is filled only, white tick going from bottom to top right as expected, is not working/visible.

Suggestions most welcome.

What i think is **class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"** is having some issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the SVG, the `<path>` colour needs to be specified using `stroke`. But the CSS will be using `color`.

Try setting the `stroke` to `currentColor`, which is a special colour keyword which represents the current value of `color`.

```
<path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"
      fill="none" stroke="currentColor" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"></path>
```